# Running LSODA.jl examples on Apple M1

Tags: julia, apple-m1, ode, dynamic-linking

I am trying to run some code in Julia that solves ODEs using LSODA on my M1 macbook pro. Everything works fine on my linux machine, but despite a lot of googling I cannot figure out how to solve this on my mac. The issue already appears trying to run the simple examples from the LSODA.jl [Readme](https://docs.juliahub.com/LSODA/HNvAI/0.7.0/).

So here is what I have done so far:

1. I installed the experimental Julia version 1.8.0-rc3 for macOS ARM (M-series Processor) from https://julialang.org/downloads/
2. In a Julia console, I tried installing the LSODA.jl package running `] add LSODA`, which produces:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> add LSODA
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.8/Project.toml`
  [7f56f5a3] + LSODA v0.7.0
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.8/Manifest.toml`
  [9e28174c] + BinDeps v1.0.2
  [7f56f5a3] + LSODA v0.7.0
  [30578b45] + URIParser v0.4.1
  [aae0fff6] + LSODA_jll v0.1.1+0
```

3. If I then try to run the minimal example from the LSODA Readme, I get the following output (see the edit at the bottom as I copied the wrong error):

```
julia> using LSODA

julia> function rhs!(t, x, ydot, data)
               ydot[1]=1.0E4 * x[2] * x[3] - .04E0 * x[1]
               ydot[3]=3.0E7 * x[2] * x[2]
               ydot[2]=-ydot[1] - ydot[3]
         nothing
       end
rhs! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> y0 = [1.,0.,0.]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> tspan = [0., 0.4]
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.4

julia> res =  lsoda(rhs!, y0, tspan, reltol= 1e-4, abstol = Vector([1.e-6,1.e-10,1.e-6]))
ERROR: UndefVarError: lsoda not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[7]:1
```

4. That suggested that julia cannot actually find the underlying lsoda library. So I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/sdwfrost/liblsoda) to build the library from scratch. That seemed to work as the generated `liblsoda.dylib` library allowed me to run the tests successfully (I got the same output as mentioned on the LSODA github).
5. At this point I have no idea how to tell julia to actually use this library. I have tried to rebuild the julia LSODA package running `] build LSODA` (running `] test LSODA` produces the same error as above btw), launching julia from within the library directory, setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the location of the library ... BUT NOTHING WORKS. I still get the same output as shown above, when running the example.
6. Just to check that I didn't mess up something with the julia installation itself, I ran the following ODE solving example using a different solver (`Tsit5()` from the `OrdinaryDiffEq` package) and that works without issues, giving the following output:

```
julia> using OrdinaryDiffEq

julia> function rhs!(du, u, p, t)
           du[1]=1.0E4 * u[2] * u[3] - .04E0 * u[1]
           du[3]=3.0E7 * u[2] * u[2]
           du[2]=-du[1] - du[3]
         nothing
       end
rhs! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> y0 = [1.,0.,0.]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> tspan = (0., 0.4)
(0.0, 0.4)

julia> prob = ODEProblem(rhs!,y0,tspan)
ODEProblem with uType Vector{Float64} and tType Float64. In-place: true
timespan: (0.0, 0.4)
u0: 3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> sol = solve(prob, Tsit5())
retcode: Success
Interpolation: specialized 4th order "free" interpolation
t: 281-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0014148463701573728
 0.002044917824570354
 0.0031082395219656383
 0.004077786184478819
 0.005515331547111039
 0.007190039901585917
 0.009125371178864151
 0.011053910882556455
 0.012779075887510953
 ⋮
 0.38962386292571205
 0.39105986979707663
 0.3924964595438138
 0.39393300822861893
 0.3953689357731328
 0.39680395859574674
 0.3982382036135917
 0.3996721389859908
 0.4
u: 281-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
 [0.9999434113374243, 3.283958368828848e-5, 2.3749078887421564e-5]
 [0.9999182177955453, 3.554267892392701e-5, 4.623952553065492e-5]
 [0.9998757150665857, 3.630246922738996e-5, 8.798246418685756e-5]
 [0.9998369766423073, 3.6462803069599716e-5, 0.00012656055462304005]
 [0.9997795672802454, 3.646643085493869e-5, 0.00018396628889956693]
 [0.9997127287562698, 3.6447280004319005e-5, 0.00025082396372578164]
 [0.9996355450580071, 3.636681631277154e-5, 0.00032808812568000767]
 [0.99955869263762, 3.601892856283502e-5, 0.0004052884338170678]
 [0.9994899965749859, 3.4686952113841286e-5, 0.00047531647290014134]
 ⋮
 [0.9855287248204975, 3.3380535729784715e-5, 0.01443789464377367]
 [0.9854791547754341, 3.3371763645216536e-5, 0.01448747346092161]
 [0.985429589879464, 3.3361195969757255e-5, 0.014537048924567189]
 [0.9853800515675893, 3.3349731795215403e-5, 0.014586598700616432]
 [0.9853305597195883, 3.3338642943875154e-5, 0.014636101637468868]
 [0.9852811239988389, 3.33290122744337e-5, 0.014685546988887663]
 [0.9852317399743383, 3.332125091318715e-5, 0.014734938774749495]
 [0.9851823915340508, 3.331492718519977e-5, 0.014784293538765007]
 [0.985171094472304, 3.359314691926523e-5, 0.01479531238077784]
```

At this point, I am rather lost, so any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:
I managed to copy the wrong error in the above description of the problem. Point 3 gives the following error output:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: liblsoda not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] lsoda_prepare
   @ ~/.julia/packages/LSODA/En9TK/src/types_and_consts.jl:88 [inlined]
 [2] lsoda(f::Function, y0::Vector{Float64}, tspan::Vector{Float64}; userdata::Nothing, reltol::Float64, abstol::Vector{Float64}, nbsteps::Int64)
   @ LSODA ~/.julia/packages/LSODA/En9TK/src/solver.jl:97
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided binaries was missing the build for Mac M1/M2. It was now updated to have these binaries https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/Yggdrasil/pull/6918 and related threads have mentioned that solved it https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-while-using-lsoda/100614/16. So if you update it should now be okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
julia> res =  lsoda(rhs!, y0, tspan, reltol= 1e-4, abstol = Vector([1.e-6,1.e-10,1.e-6]))
ERROR: UndefVarError: lsoda not defined
Stacktrace:
```

> That suggested that julia cannot actually find the underlying lsoda library.

eh, no, `lsoda` is not the underlying library or anything, just the `lsoda()` is not defined, most likely because `LSODA.jl` does not export it.

but in any case this works for me just fine

```
julia> using LSODA

julia> LSODA.lsoda
lsoda

julia> lsoda
lsoda
```

can you double check you have the correct pkg version installed?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I managed to copy the wrong error above, so I edited the post. That would suggest that julia can't see the library, wouldn't it? Regarding your suggestion, I can run the three commands with exactly the same output as you ... no error, but actually using the solver causes the issue. As I showed under point 2, I installed LSODA.jl v0.7.0. But I also just tried with v0.6.2 and the same issue arises.

Comment: @Vanessa can you try the Rosetta version of the Julia instead of M-series?

Comment: Just tried with Rosetta v1.7.3 and the above example works. Thanks for the tip. However, as I eventually need to call Julia from within Python code and that requires the PyCall package, I am now running into issues as the Julia Rosetta version doesn't seem to like the arm python installation. While I am trying to figure out if I can get that to work, could I ask if you know how to get Julia to recognise a specific library? As I said above, I built the library that Julia can't find from scratch. I just don't know how to tell Julia where exactly to find it. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I think the cleanest solution is to add M-series support here: https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/Yggdrasil/blob/master/L/LSODA/build_tarballs.jl

Comment: As I am new to julia, would you be able to explain what you mean by that? Or rather how to do that? Looking at the supported platforms at https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinaryBuilderBase.jl/blob/4b21cde2105830e287271c323d909b9ee8a64c5e/src/Rootfs.jl#L714 I thought this would mean that M1 support should already be included.

Comment: not in the recipe for LSODA